# How to pass State in Context React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

Im trying to pass and update a state with `useContext`;

App.js

```
import Home from './components/Home'
const UserContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Name');

  return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{name, setName}}>
        <Home/>
      </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import UserContext from '../../App'

function Home() {
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <>
        <label>Your name:</label>
        <input type='text' onChange={e => user.setName(e.target.value)} />
        <p>{user.name}</p>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Im getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name');

How is the correct way to pass state between components with useContext?

Comment: The code you have posted does not match the error you are receiving. Firstly, it would not compile since you do not export the `UserContext`. Which means you cannot import it into your `Home` Component. Once you have done that, your app does work. I've copy pasted your code into a Create-react-app and it works.

Comment: How do I export context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to export your UserContext, so it can be imported in the components that need it:

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Name');

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ name, setName }}>
      <Home />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Afterwards you can import it in your App component:

```
import { UserContext } '../../App'

function Home() {
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <>
            <label>Your name:</label>
            <input type='text' onChange={e => user.setName(e.target.value)} />
            <p>{user.name}</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I didnt know that, thx alot

Comment: If you need a variable in a file and it is not defined in that file using `const`, `let` or `var` - you need import it. IF you need to import it, it has to be exported in some other file.

Comment: I thought the `<.Provider>` was exporting it to all the children somehow

Comment: Simple and elegant

Answer (score 8):

**1. Setting parent state for dynamic context**

Firstly, in order to have a dynamic context which can be passed to the consumers, I'll use the parent's state. This ensures that I've a single source of truth going forth. For example, my parent App will look like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("John");
  const value = { name, setName };

  return (
   ...
  );
};
```

The **name** is stored in the state. We will pass both **name** and the setter function **setName** via context later.

**2. Creating a context**

Next, I created a **name** context like this:

```
// set the defaults
const NameContext = React.createContext({
  name: "John",
  setName: () => {}
});
```

Here I'm setting the defaults for **name** ('John') and a **setName** function which will be sent by the context provider to the consumer(s). These are only defaults and I'll provide their values when using the provider component in the parent App.

**3. Creating a context consumer**

In order to have the name switcher set the **name** and also showing, it should have the access to the name setter function via context. It can look something like this:

```
const NameSwitcher = () => {
const { name, setName } = useContext(NameContext);
 return (
    <label>Your name:</label><br />
    <input type='text' onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
    <p>{name}</p>
  );
};
```

Here I'm just setting the **name** to input value but you may have your own logic to set name for this.

**4. Wrapping the consumer in a provider**

Now I'll render my name switcher component in a NameContext.Provider and pass in the values which have to be sent via context to any level deeper. Here's how my parent App look like:

```
const App = () => {
   const [name, setName] = useState("John");
   const value = { name, setName };

   return (
    <Name.Provider value={value}>
      <NameSwitcher />
    </Name.Provider>
   );
};
```