# Sending data from utility file to a component (React + Vite)

Tags: reactjs, vite, appwrite

I've got a file called `LoginPage.jsx` which calls a function in a utility file called `AuthContext.jsx`, the utility file handles the request to the backend server to authenticate a user. If no user is found or any other error is returned, how do I send that back to the `LoginPage.jsx` file to be handled and displayed to the user?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to pass error from context to component is to use a custom hook that wraps the `useContext` function and throws an error if the context is undefined. This way, you can access the context value in any component that uses the hook, and handle the error accordingly. For example, you can create a `useUserContext` hook like this:

```
const useUserContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useUserContext was used outside of its Provider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

Then, in your `AuthContext.jsx` file, you can set the error state in the catch block of your `fetch` request, and pass it along with the `user` and `signout` values to the `UserContext.Provider`:

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const signout = () => setUser(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = () => {
      fetch("https://localhost:8000/api/")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => setUser(result.results))
        .catch((error) => setError(error)); // set error state here
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({ user, signout, error }), // pass error value here
    [user, signout, error]
  );

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Finally, in your `LoginPage.jsx` file, you can use the useUserContext hook to access the error value and display it to the user if it exists:

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const { user, signout, error } = useUserContext(); // use custom hook here

  return (
    <div className="login-page">
      {user ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome, {user.name.first}</h1>
          <button onClick={signout}>Sign out</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Please log in</h1>
          {error && <p className="error-message">{error.message}</p>} // display
          error message here
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

To learn more, see

- [how to use React Context like a pro](https://devtrium.com/posts/how-use-react-context-pro)
- [how to pass state in context React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69419839/how-to-pass-state-in-context-react)
- [how to pass context into a component instantiated with
  ReactDOM.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212174/is-it-possible-to-pass-context-into-a-component-instantiated-with-reactdom-rende)
- [React Context API: A deep dive with examples](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-context-api-deep-dive-examples/)